# Sort child nodes by date - Razor Umbraco

Tags: c#, list, razor, sql-order-by, umbraco

For the following examples, I'm using a content tree which looks like this:
[Content tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNU7G.jpg)

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    var home = Model.Content.Descendants().Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "BlogContainer");

    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in home)
            {
                foreach (var items in item.Children)
                {
                    foreach (var baby in items.Children.OrderBy("date desc"))
                    {
                        var date = baby.GetPropertyValue<DateTime>("date");

                        <li>@items.Name - @baby.Name - @date</li>
                    }
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

And the result is [Result three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtGg5.jpg) I need to collect all items and set order by date

Answer (score 3):

Try and do something like

```
var allItems = homePage.Descendants("YourItemNodeType")
            .Where(item => item.HasValue("date")
                              && item.GetPropertyValue<DateTime>
                                  ("date") != DateTime.MinValue)
            .ToList()
            .OrderByDescending(item => item.GetPropertyValue<DateTime>("date"));
```

This should get you all your items in both category 1 and category 2, i always tend to check if my date is actually set ( you wouldnt need to do that for create date mentioned by @bowserm as that is always there with a value).

Once u got them to List then you can sort them by their set date, i do this on when i list news articles in different parent pages, then you can just have one loop to go through all of them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what Umbraco version are you using? It looks like you are using 6+? Is that right? My answer below should work for 6 and 7.

The property you are looking for is called `createDate`, so you would use something like `baby.GetPropertyValue<DateTime>("createDate")`. Even better, you should be able to just type `baby.CreateDate`. Umbraco has exposed all of the default properties that you might want on the IPublishedContent as properties, so you can get at those without having to use `GetPropretyValue(...)`.

Take a look at this [Umbraco v6 MVC Razor Cheatsheet](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-v6-mvc-razor-cheatsheets). It lists the default properties you can get off of the nodes in Umbraco. The razor syntax for v6 will also be applicable to v7, so this cheat sheet works for both.

Comment: It's Umbraco 7. And yes `createDate` gives same result that I had already.

I need collection of all parent child, what I get too, but ordering is only under parent node. `date` is just `propertyValue` from custom Date Picker.

Check the link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UtGg5.jpg